# Is FaqOverflow part of Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

Recently I found a website called [FaqOverflow](http://www.faqoverflow.com/). Is this a new Stack Exchange website?

Comment: Man, that is one ugly website.

Comment: I've seen a lot worse. Check out the website for the company "Fabric Land" (not linked here to save your eyes)

Comment: @NickUdell: I can beat that. Look up "Leffingwell and Associates".

Comment: @NickUdell You are from UK, so probably you have tried to show case [this](http://www.fabricland.co.uk/). Right.? :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: OMG! That is worse than the Fabric Land I found (a US site, which still wasn't great).

Comment: This was [asked on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224295/is-this-site-which-seems-to-be-copying-the-content-from-stackexchange-sites-le) a few months ago, too. Not much info there, just linking it in case anyone ends up at this post thinking of that one.

Comment: @Pops But kranzky Dont answer to that question!

Comment: Yep, I'm not criticizing, this is a fine question (and indeed, due to kranzky's answer, the better of the two). I was just trying to reduce confusion for people who remembered the other post.

Comment: FaqOverflow has been [slashdotted](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slashdotted).

Comment: @NickUdell You haven’t seen http://taxipoll.nl/.

Comment: @elyse this picture from that site is begging to be turned into meme status: http://taxipoll.nl/klhalazg.jpg

Comment: Now [closed due to a copyright troll](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427272/am-i-liable-for-re-sharing-image-links-provided-via-the-stack-exchange-api/427273#427273).

Comment: In the upper right corner of any StackExchange webpage, you have access to "A list of all 183 Stack Exchange sites", and if it's not in there, it's not part of the Stack Exchange websites :-)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Blame me; I wrote [FaqOverflow](http://www.faqoverflow.com/) as a hobby project back in 2010. It gets about 20k uniques a month. I only occasionally run the script to update it (it's a static website hosted on S3). It uses the API responsibly to collect the data it uses.

I was very careful before launch to make sure that it did satisfy the guidelines, so I'm upset to hear that I may be flaunting them :(

- I verified with someone at SE that it was in compliance
- The cc-wiki license is declared
- Each topic links back to the relevant StackExchange site with a banner of the form "shared and re-mixed from the Stack Overflow Q&A site"
- Each question links back to the original question and to the user's page
- Each answer links back to the original answer and to the user's page
- Project announced on StackApps and had positive feedback
- I have received two emails from someone at SE team since launch that questioned compliance, and each agreed that I complied after I pointed out the aforementioned links

My intent with FO was to present the StackExchange sites as a browsable collection of the "best" questions and answers, because that was a problem that I had at the time: I wanted to flip through topics on my phone (which may explain the layout) and discover and learn new things, rather than find an answer to a specific question.

Anyway, I'll happily yank it if that's what the community wants (and I'll redirect the domain to https://stackexchange.com/). Alternatively, I'll happily reimplement it to clarify attribution and better solve the problem of "serendipitous discovery" if there's still no great solution to that, and if people think a better implementation would serve a useful purpose?

And if the latter, perhaps someone with some design chops can help me de-uglify things :)

#### Update

FAQoverflow has now been deleted due to a copyright claim. See the [discussion thread](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97479) for information.

Comment: I'm curious how you pick questions to grab.  Is it just you picking questions or automated?  I think it might be interesting to try to automatically grab cannonical (or close to it) answers.  Maybe suck up every question who's highest answer is scored 2 or 3x the average for its most popular tag?  That might make for interesting reading.

Comment: @GabeSechan I guess the questions were from `/votes`... which are quite appropriate as FAQ?

Comment: Personally, I don't see this as a problem, given that I can recognize that they are shared from StackExchange sites immediately after clicking the category. Moreover, *I believe I have read an idea like this somewhere (to make an FAQ for StackOverflow)*, though I can't remember where...

Comment: @kranzky de-uglyfy: have a look at blog.fefe.de and use his design, I love it and its totally mobile-device compatible.

Comment: If you see a sudden spike in visitors, thank [@gun2171](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266586/is-faqoverflow-part-of-stack-exchange-websites#comment66566_266586)

Comment: You might also want to add your app to http://stackapps.com/

Comment: FaqOverflow has been reported to the team as a SCRAPER a few times, but it is playing nice with our rules. (Some well-meaning SE users see any republished SE content and report it to us without realizing that there are valid ways to reuse it.) It also complies with our [trademark guidelines](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), which state that you're welcome to use "Stack" or "Overflow" in your name, just not both. For what it's worth, here's the comment I wrote about it on our internal list last October: "compliant (and actually kinda nice-looking)" Nice work, kranzky!

Comment: That said, it _would_ be nice if the indication of the original site was a bit more prominent. I'm pretty sure I wouldn't have noticed it if I hadn't been specifically scouring the page for it. But as things are now, we're not going to come after you or anything.

Comment: @GabeSechan It takes the top 10k questions sorted by votes, ignoring closed questions or ones with few answers, and assigns a quality score to those remaining. This is calculated by a heuristic that favours short questions, answers of about a page in length, high scoring questions, high scoring answers, and answers that score significantly better than the second best answer. It then buckets questions into "chapters", sorts these chapters by average question quality, discards chapters with too few questions or too low quality, and generates a bunch of static HTML with what's left.

Comment: Thanks @Pops, I take your point about prominence, I'll look at that first if I dust this project off and make some changes.

Answer (score 22):

No, it isn't.

There is no affiliation.

Looks like someone who took the data-dump and remixed it (if you actually drill down to a question/answer, you will see that's what they say).

All content is licensed as [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with attribution required, so anyone can re-use it. They are linking back to the user (good), but are not visually indicating that it came from here (bad - it makes it look like the user wrote it directly on that site.)

So they're not in full compliance with our attribution guidelines, but are less abusive than some others.

Comment: The data use is fine, but Stack Exchange Inc. might me able to make a case against the similarity of the "FAQ Overflow" name to their trademarked "Stack Overflow" name.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - does Stack Exchange Inc. strike you as a litigious entity?

Comment: The [Trademark Guidance](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) page says "With open access to use (and reuse) our services, **it is important that users not be confused by our relationship with the people who use our content and our services**" (emphasis mine). It looks like they have at least considered this possibility.

Comment: Sorry if I don't get it, but what does it mean to "visually indicate"?

Comment: @gitsitgo: It means they should clearly indicate (so that it's clearly **visible to the visitor** where the data was obtained) in accordance with the terms of use. Visual means "able to be seen".

Comment: Actually he does say at the top of each section: "{ shared and re-mixed from the Stack Overflow Q&A site }", is this not enough attribution (it is a link)?

Comment: @Sammaye - do you call that _clear_? Agreed, that's a judgement call, but most users won't notice that at all.

Comment: @Oded I saw it at first glance, it might be a judgement call, but I'd call it clear.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Maybe if he changes it to FaqUnderflow that would avoid the trademark issue. ;)

Comment: @Angelo I agree. The only thing that's unclear is everything, because of the horrible design.